# Set post data for password field using asp.net url

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

I'm trying to login to this asp.net [page](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoqt) from my PHP code, (set username field value, set password field value, press button and then check where it is redirected.) I can set the username field, but for some reason I cannot set the password field (see line 226 in HTML file).

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/518/login.aspx";
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

$username = "XXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXX";


$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose

/**
    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

/**
 Start Login process
 */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "m_Content_submitbtn2";
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['m$Content$username2'] = $username;
$postfields['m$Content$password2'] = $password;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
print $last_url;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the password seems to be sent through the POST field `m$Content$passwordHidden`. Try changing `$postfields['m$Content$password2'] = $password;` to `$postfields['m$Content$passwordHidden'] = $password;`

Edit:
I found something else you can change. When I send a login request I have `__EVENTTARGET` set to `m$Content$submitbtn2` and `__VIEWSTATEX` instead of `__VIEWSTATE` so:

```
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEX" id="__VIEWSTATEX" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
...
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "m$Content$submitbtn2";
...
$postfields['__VIEWSTATEX'] = $viewstate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it's the same. Nothing happens.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoqs in that case it's not working.

Comment: I just needed to input correct username and password instead of the X's. It's working perfectly now, thanks a ton!